# How to get the title attribute and append somewhere else

Tags: jquery, insert, get, attributes, title

How to get the title attribute  and append somewhere else?

I have this code below:

```
<div class="span">
 <a title="SHARON MORGAN" href="/members/SHARONMORGAN">
    <span class="avatar avatar-96 avatar-default"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

That I want change like this:

```
<div class="span">
 <a title="SHARON MORGAN" href="/members/SHARONMORGAN">
    <span class="avatar avatar-96 avatar-default"></span>
 </a>
 <a href="/members/SHARONMORGAN">SHARON MORGAN</a>
</div>
```

Notice the name SHARON MORGAN is inserted next to the anchor tag and is wrap with the same link above it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `after` method for generating the new element. `this` in the function's callback refers to the selected element(s), so you can use `this.title`, `this.getAttribute('title')` or `$(this).attr('title')` for getting the title value:

```
$('div.span a').after(function() {
    return $('<a/>', {
        href: this.href,
        text: this.title
    });
});
```

Or using vanilla JS:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.span a')).forEach(function(el) {
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   a.href = el.href;
   a.textContent = el.title;
   el.parentNode.insertBefore(a, el.nextSibling);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y2goyvvm/

Answer (score 1):

With a basic jquery statement:

```
$(function() {
    $('[title="SHARON MORGAN"]').each(function() {
        $(this.parentNode).append('<a href=\"' + this.href + '\">' + this.title + '</a>');
    });
});
```

Comment: `\"` can simply be `"`.

Comment: Regent, do you want our help? As for know you only tell us what we do wrong in our answers but obviously you have no idea about JavaScript or jquery. It sucks dude.

Comment: @BarthZalewski I'm trying to improve your answers. I have enough knowledge of JS and jQuery, don't worry about it. Is there something incorrect in my words?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you would have to grab the element somehow and read ist title attribute. Then you can do what you want with it.

```
<a title="SHARON MORGAN" id="sharon-morgan" href="..."><span>...</span></a>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
var title = $('a#sharon-morgan').attr('title');
var href = $('a#sharon-morgan').attr('href');
var a = $('<a href="' + href + '">' + title + '</a>').appendTo('body');
</script>
```

Of course this is just an example, because you didn't specify too many details. Have a look at jQuery, it's done exactly for stuff like this.

Comment: `appendTo()` has to be to `'.span'`, not to `'body'`.

Comment: Moreover, why do you add `id` to element? There are a lot of way to select this `<a>` element without `id`.

Comment: I said it's just an EXAMPLE, because there are hundreds of ways to do this. And I can't see you appending anything to a span element, but much more creating a new a-element and appending to after the first one to the parent element. And why id? Also as an example. Somehow you have to grab the element.